# http.get and http.post through error in scheduled script Netsuite - Error: Cannot find function post in object

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm using schedule script and http.get method but throws error as "Cannot find function get in object".
code snapshot:

```
var headers_= []
headers_["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
headers_["Accept"] = "appli`enter code here`cation/json";  
headers_["cache-control"] = "no-cache";

var response = http.get({
        url: URL_,          
        headers: headers_
    });
```

Comment: How are you loading the http module?

Comment: define(['N/search', 'N/record', 'N/runtime', 'N/format',,'N/task','N/http'] like this

Comment: @bknights: any help would be appreaciated

Comment: Please include your complete module; the problem is very likely in your `define` statement.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh How to include the complete module. we just use define('N/http'){function(http){}} Is there any other way please let me know

Comment: You've answered the question about module loading two different ways (unless that's a markdown issue)  `define('N/http'){function(http){}}` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `define` statement. It should be:

```
define(["N/http"], function (http) {
  ...
});
```

If there are other dependencies as well, double-check that the order of the dependencies in the Array matches exactly the order of the parameters in the callback.

If the order matches exactly, make sure you don't have a typo in the parameter name you use for the http module.

Comment: I have a feeling NetSuite won't like this symbol `. 
Try replace with '. 
If not, try N/https rather than N/http